# Preserve indentation when setting value of Ace editor

Tags: javascript, string, ace-editor

How can you preserve the indentation of a string that is push into Ace editor by `.setValue()`?
Now, when I push a string into the editor, all the indentation is lost and it has this weird typewriter spacing:
assuming the typewriter is `|`
if

```
string to edit here with four space->    |
```

if I press backspace,:

```
string to edit here with four space-   |
```

I dont know why this happen, please help

Answer (score 0):

Looks like Ace calculates wrong cursor position.
This can happen either if your editor have non monospace font.
Or because of this [bug](https://github.com/ajaxorg/ace/issues/1534) if you are using Safari on Mac OS X 10.8